# QT network programming: the function of incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor) can't be automatic invoked when a new connection is available

Tags: c++, qt

here is my code:`int`
the overwrite virtual function is:

```
void TcpServer::incomingConnection(int socketDescriptor)
{

    TcpSocket *tcpSocket = new TcpSocket(this);
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(updateClients(QString,int)),
        this, SLOT(updateClients(QStrstrong,int)));
    connect(tcpSocket, SIGNAL(disconnected(int)),
        this, SLOT(tcpDisconnected(int)));

    tcpSocket->setSocketDescriptor(socketDescriptor);
    tcpSocketList.append(tcpSocket);

    return emit QTcpServer::newConnection ();
}
```

**the constructor of the child class of QTcpServer is here:**

```
TcpServer::TcpServer(QObject *parent, int port) :
QTcpServer(parent)
{

    if(this->listen (QHostAddress::Any,port))
    {
        qDebug("invocation!!!");

    }
    else
    {
        qDebug("disinvocation!!!");


    }
 }
```

when Client execute the function:**tcpSocket->connectToHost(ipAddress, port);**
function incomingConnection() can't be invoked!
why? It confused me for long time. Thanks!!

Comment: If you use Qt5, change `socketDescriptor` argument type to `qintptr`.

Comment: @PavelStrakhov  thank you very mach! 'Qstring'